# Copy files from S3 bucket to any destination (like sharepoint) other than S3 bucket

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-java

Under AWS JAVA SDK, I can see AmazonS3.java, TransferManager.java for copying/transferring files between two S3 buckets.  I want to know what can be used when the destination is NOT a S3 bucket.
I have a requirement where I need to transfer from S3 bucket to SharePoint but under AWS Java SDK I can't find any utility to copy/move files from S3 bucket  to any destination other than another bucket. Please help.

Comment: Did you consider S3 -> fileobj (or even local disk) -> Sharepoint?  (Just an idea.. I know nothing about SP.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general solution is to use `S3Client.getObject(objectRequest)` which is a [`ResponseInputStream<GetObjectResponse>`](https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/core/ResponseInputStream.html).  This AWS specific object is subclass of the standard `java.io.InputStream`.

So all you need to do is read that stream...

1. indirectly into a File, and then pass the file handle to your Sharepoint client
2. indirectly into an in-memory byte store (if there's enough RAM), and then pass the `byte[]` to your Sharepoint client
3. or open up an output stream on your Sharepoint client and stream from S3 to Sharepoint directly.

The actual byte moving could be assisted with a tool such as [Apache Commons IO: `IOUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html)